# Expression expected near left join... where am i wrong in this query please

Tags: mysql

```
select `tbl_users`.`username`, `tbl_users`.`users_id`, `tbl_users`.`profile_picture`, 
   (select count(users_id) from tbl_movies_comments where users_id = `tbl_users`.`users_id`) as UsersCommentsCount, 
   (select count(users_id) from tbl_movies_reviews where users_id = `tbl_users`.`users_id`) as UserReviewsCount 
left join `tbl_movies_comments` on `tbl_users`.`users_id` = `tbl_movies_comments`.`users_id` 
left join `tbl_movies_reviews` on `tbl_users`.`users_id` = `tbl_movies_reviews`.`users_id` 
group by `tbl_users`.`username`, `tbl_users`.`users_id`, `tbl_users`.`profile_picture`,  `tbl_movies_comments`.`users_id`, `tbl_movies_reviews`.`users_id`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no FROM clause in your query.

```
SELECT ...
FROM `tbl_users`
LEFT JOIN ...
```

Comment: Thanks brother .. my bad i am a little weak in query building. :(

Comment: @ShehriyarNadeemVohra, no problem. Don't forget to mark the answer as Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is really bad formatted. This is one reason why its hard to debug code...

```
....

  (
    SELECT
      Count(users_id)
    FROM
      tbl_movies_reviews
    WHERE
      users_id = tbl_users.users_id
  ) AS userreviewscount

FROM yourtablename    <<<--- Missing

    left JOIN tbl_movies_comments 
        ON tbl_users.users_id = tbl_movies_comments.users_id
....
```

Use tools like HeidiSQL or an online Syntax formatter/checker to avoid such situations